# Fancytree edit extension disable aspx button click

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-events, fancytree

I have a simple aspx page with one button and one fancytree.

The button click event runs a web method on server side to save the tree content.
Everything runs ok and I am able to load and save the info in a database.

My problem is when I use the edit extension on the tree.  Especially when I hit enter to save the new title of a node.  The enter Key seems to disable my button click after.  Has anybody used the edit extension of a fancytree on a aspx page?

I just can't figure out why my button click doesn't work after I press enter to confirm the new node title.

Here is the button:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClientClick="SaveTree()" />
```

Here is the Javascript:

```
 //Save tree
    function SaveTree() {


        //Get information
        var actid = getUrlVars()["activityid"];
        var name = $("#<%= txtName.ClientID %>");
        var desc = $("#<%= txtDescription.ClientID %>");
        var plantid = $("#<%= ddlPlant.ClientID %>");


      
        if (Page_ClientValidate()) {
            var tree = $("#tree").fancytree("getTree");
            var d = tree.toDict(true);
            var test = JSON.stringify(d);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "EditTree.aspx/SaveTree",
                data: "{treeData:'" + test + "',name:'" + name.val() + "',desc:'" + desc.val() + "',actid:'" + actid + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg.d);
                    window.location = "Default.aspx?plantid=" + plantid.val();
                }
            });
        }

    }
```

And here is the tree:

```
$(function () {

    
    var me = getUrlVars()["activityid"];

    
    $("#tree").fancytree({

        ajax: { type: "GET", contentType: "application/json" },
        source: { url: "EditTree.aspx/GetTreeData", cache: false, data: { activityid: me } },

        activeVisible: true,
        autoActivate: true,
        autoScroll: true,
        keyboard: true,
        selectMode: 1,

        extensions: ["edit", "dnd"],

        edit: {
            adjustWidthOfs: 4,              // null: don't adjust input size to content
            inputCss: { minWidth: "3em" },
            triggerStart: ["f2"],           //l'édition se fait à partir de la touche F2
            beforeEdit: $.noop,             // Return false to prevent edit mode
            edit: $.noop,                   // Editor was opened (available as data.input)
            beforeClose: $.noop,            // Return false to prevent cancel/save (data.input is available)
            save: $.noop,                   // Save data.input.val() or return false to keep editor open
            close: $.noop,                  // Editor was removed
        } etc...
```

Comment: Ok I just found out that the click event is always hit and the server side code is running also.  The problem seems to be in the success of the ajax call.  What could be the reason the javascript alert in the success would not show up even if there is a good returned value?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.  Ajax stands for Asynchronous.  So the call to the webmethod on the server side was always running.  But the alert in the success was not because I was not waiting for the response.  I just added **async: false** in the ajax call and now it is working.

```
$.ajax({
    async: false,        
    success: function(data) {
       //alert...
    }
});
```

Great!